# Cannot create a mapping profile (DTO => entity)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, backend, automapper, dto

I'm using NestJs with https://github.com/nartc/mapper (automapper).
I really love this library but it doesn't come with structured documentation for NestJs, so a lot of errors aren't documented.
In my others entities it just works and I'm doing the same thing
when I create this map:
`createMap(mapper, CreateUserDto, User);`
I'm getting this error:
`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
please help me 
here's my DTO and my entity:
DTO:

```js
import { IsArray, IsEmail, IsEnum, IsNotEmpty, IsNumber, IsOptional, IsString, ValidateNested } from "class-validator";
import { Type } from "class-transformer";
import { Scope } from "src/scope/scope.enum";
import { Status } from "src/status/status.enum";
import { ReadDepartmentDto } from "src/department/dept.dto";
import { ReadProjectDto } from "src/project/project.dto";
import { AutoMap } from "@automapper/classes";

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @AutoMap()
  department!: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true})
  @IsNumber()
  @AutoMap()
  isRefBusinessOf?: number[];

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true})
  @IsNumber()
  @AutoMap()
  isProjectManagerOf?: number[];

  @IsEmail() 
  @AutoMap()
  email!: string;
  
  @IsString()
  @AutoMap()
  firstname!: string;
  
  @IsString()
  @AutoMap()
  lastname!: string;
  
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @AutoMap()
  avatarUrl?: string;
  
  @IsEnum(Scope, { each: true })
  @AutoMap()
  scopes!: Scope[];
  
  @IsEnum(Status, { each: true })
  @AutoMap()
  statuses!: Status[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @AutoMap()
  password!: string;
}
```

entity:

```js
import { Scope } from "src/scope/scope.enum";
import { Exclude, instanceToPlain } from "class-transformer";
import { Department } from "src/department/dept.entity";
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Project } from "src/project/project.entity";
import { Status } from "src/status/status.enum";
import { AutoMap } from "@automapper/classes";

@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @AutoMap(() => Department)
  @ManyToOne(() => Department, (department: Department) => department.users, { nullable: true })
  department!: Department;

  @AutoMap(() => [Project])
  @OneToMany(() => Project, (project: Project) => project.projectManager, { nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
  isProjectManagerOf?: Project[];

  @AutoMap(() => [Project])
  @OneToMany(() => Project, (project: Project) => project, { nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
  isRefBusinessOf?: Project[];

  @AutoMap()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  email!: string;

  @AutoMap()
  @Column()
  firstname!: string;

  @AutoMap()
  @Column()
  lastname!: string;

  @AutoMap()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  avatarUrl?: string;

  @AutoMap()
  @Column({ 
    type: "enum", 
    enum: Scope,
    default: [Scope.Admin],
    array: true, 
  })
  scopes!: Scope[];
  
  @AutoMap()
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Status,
    default: [Status.Active],
    array: true,
  })
  statuses!: Status[]
  
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  passwordSalt?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  rtrs?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  passwordHash?: string;
  
  toJSON() {
    return instanceToPlain(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not post images of code in your question, but rather copy in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pretty sure that library [has documentation on integrating with Nest](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs)

Comment: It's not so complete that documentation

Answer (score 1):

From

https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/strategies/classes#enum

and

https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/strategies/classes#array-type

In both your files(DTO, entity), add to your enum fields:

```
@AutoMap(() => [String])
```

your code become :

**DTO**

```
@IsEnum(Status, { each: true })
@AutoMap(() => [String])
statuses!: Status[];
```

**Entity**

```
@AutoMap(() => [String])
@Column({
    type: 'string',
    enum: Status,
    default: [Status.Active],
    array: true,
  })
  statuses!: Status[]
```